# What are the best practices when it comes to dynamically resizing SVG elements?

Tags: html, css, svg, frontend

I've been working on the [Order Summary Component](https://www.frontendmentor.io/challenges/order-summary-component-QlPmajDUj) challenge from FrontEnd Mentor and am a little confused about dynamically resizing `<svg/>` elements.  Just want to make sure I”m doing things correctly as I don’t know much about CSS.

My questions are as follows:

1. I’m placing the background pattern as a sibling to the card
   component, setting the container to `position: relative` and the
   `.background` div to `position: absolute; inset: 0;`. Is this the correct method to float a background image behind a card? Or should
   I be going about it differently?
2. I set the svg `viewbox` to match the provided `width` and `height` of the
   element and removed the `width` and `height` (from `width="450" height="220"` to `viewbox="0 0 450 220`). I then set the
   `.background` div to `overflow: hidden;` which clips the pattern as the viewport is resized horizontally. Is this correct? Or should I be
   trying to dynamically resize the svg so that the pattern scales with
   the container width in addition to the height?
3. When I zoom into the card I get a `1px` gap between the `svg` element and the card. Why is that?
   I've added a solid border to see what’s going on with the box model of the
   card. Should I make the svg slightly larger using the viewbox attribute?
   Am I splitting hairs here? Does this even matter? It looks fine at 100% zoom but shows up with 110%, 125%, 150%, 175%, and then disappears again at 200%.

[**CodeSandbox Link**](https://codesandbox.io/s/order-summary-component-challenge-hsg1k?file=/src/styles.css&resolutionWidth=1024&resolutionHeight=765)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've done a good job there, congratulations.

For **1.**, my 2 cents is that `inset: 0;` is a shortcut for `top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;`, and this later has broader compatibility.

For **2.**, I think you're good.

Finally, the last problem, which is the most difficult to solve, has been discussed as sub pixel rendering of SVG. There is a nice compromise workaround for your case: set the `article`'s `background-color: rgb(30, 31, 205);`, and the `section.card-content`'s `background-color: white;`. This will fix the zoom for any percentage value (or else, you could try to tweak the width/height and viewBox and some of the zooms will be fixed, but not all. This workaround fixes all).

#### Edit

To make the `svg` element behave correctly regarding space around it, apply `display: block;` style to it.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response! Good to know about the `inset` property being less compatible with older browsers/machines.

re: the sub pixel rendering problem: When I apply `background-color: rgb(30, 31, 205);` I get a band below the SVG element that is part of the `section.card-hero`. A bit vexed as to why this is happening as the only thing that should be determining the size of that box is the SVG element. Any ideas as to what's going on?

Comment: Apply `display: block;` to the `svg` element.